# Unable to play movie from Youtube in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

A video from the internet like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/myvideo.m4v"];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]; 
[player play];
```

Unable to play movie on Simulator Black Screen displays

Comment: add more code. both of your controller files. the .m and .h

Answer (score 0):

You should try some frameworks (for example [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser)) that can fetch a direct link to video from Youtube for you.

```
// Gets an dictionary with each available youtube url
NSDictionary *videos = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE"]];

// Presents a MoviePlayerController with the youtube quality medium
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[videos objectForKey:@"medium"]]] autorelease];
```